# Building and debugging ARMV8 assembler applications on Windows

Tags: arm, gnu-toolchain, ds-5, armv8

I'm trying to learn ARMV8 assembler, and am trying to build a test application on Windows.  I've installed ARM DS-5 Community Edition, version 5.26.2.  After much hair pulling trying to install toolchains, I finally installed the "mingw32" toolchain here: [here](https://releases.linaro.org/components/toolchain/binaries/latest/aarch64-elf/).  This seems to work - I am now able to compile and link my application (which consists of a single c file and a .s assembly file.  The target created is a ".axf" file.

But I am unable to debug.  I have my debugger set to "\gcc-linaro-6.3.1-2017.02-i686-mingw32_aarch64-linux-gnu\bin\aarch64-linux-gnu-gdb.exe", out of the directory where I downloaded the toolchain.  gdb starts up, but I get the error below:
Error in final launch sequence
Failed to execute MI command:
-exec-run
Error message from debugger back end:
Don't know how to run.  Try "help target".
Don't know how to run.  Try "help target".

Any suggestions?  Frankly, I don't really know what I'm doing here.  I'm not sure I set up the toolchain properly.  The problem is I can't find any documentation on how to do this in windows.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Usually host  with ARM CPU/MCU is used to debug. Or you can use QEMU to emulate ARM CPU (not sure about ARMv8): https://balau82.wordpress.com/2010/08/17/debugging-arm-programs-inside-qemu/

Comment: Thanks, but I need more to go on. I've seen armv8 debugging working on DS5 under Ubuntu on x86, I can't imagine there isn't a working simulator under Windows that I can use for debugging. I just need info on how to install/configure one.